# howto measure contention rate of one lock

Tags: c#, .net, performance, performancecounter, contention

I'm currently having problems with the contention rate of a partical application (.net 4.0, c#) I'm maintaining.
What I would like to do is to write a PerfCounter if one partical lock couldn't be aquired. Right now I just have the overall counter, provided by .net, but I would like to have a PerfCounter for some selected locks.

Profiler etc. is not a option for me, as this is a high performing productive environment that I cannot touch, I can record perfcounters.

Comment: That's not going to fly, you can't just bolt a perf counter onto a lock.  You really do need a profiler, the concurrency visualizer in VS Ultimate will do nicely.  You'll need to fix the 'cannot touch' problem first.  Create a simulated runtime environment with fake data.

Answer (score 2):

ETW events may already provide information on what you need. See [ETW overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357719.aspx) and [Lock contention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356157.aspx).